# How to upgrade JUnit-5 in spring-boot 1.5.10?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit

I am using ***spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE*** and using ***spring-boot-starter-test*** for the unit test which has in-built **JUnit-1.4**. I would like to use **JUnit-1.5** in my project. I have browsed internet most of the search results links to ***spring-boot-2.0***. **Are we can't use JUnit-5 along with sprint-boot-1.5.X?**

GitHub link or hint would be really appreciable.

Comment: What builder are using?maven or gradle?

Comment: Hi thanks a lot for your reply ....I’m using Maven sorry for not mentioning that

Comment: There's no easy way to do this. You could look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41747849/junit-5-and-spring-framework-4-3-x to help solve it, but I'd recommend sticking with JUnit 4 until you can upgrade to Spring Boot 2.x, which has direct, built-in support for JUnit 5.

Comment: @VelNaga You either need to go to Spring Boot 2, or use something like https://github.com/sbrannen/spring-test-junit5 as an interim measure. Personally, I'd stick with JUnit 4 (I continue to use it even with Spring Boot 2.x, since there's nothing in JUnit 5 that I need to use).

Answer (score 1):

To migration you can review this link https://www.baeldung.com/junit-5-migration 
To dependencies using Junit 5 ,https://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/testing/junit-5-tutorial-running-unit-tests-with-maven/
If you want use spring boot starter test, should exclude dependencies stuffs related to Junit 5

```
 <dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
     <version>1.5.1.RELEASE</version>
     <scope>test</scope>
     <exclusions>
          <exclusion> 
          <!-- declare the exclusion here -->
             <groupId>sample.junit</groupId>
             <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
          </exclusion>
     </exclusions> 
 </dependency>
```

And add them according Junit 5 versions or you can declare versions

```
 <properties>
    <junit-jupiter-engine.version>5.1.0</junit-jupiter-engine.version>
    <junit-vintage-engine.version>5.1.0</junit-vintage-engine.version>
    <junit-platform-launcher.version>1.1.0</junit-platform-launcher.version>
    <junit-platform-runner.version>1.1.0</junit-platform-runner.version>
 </properties>
```

Comment: Excluding those properties and adding only these properties is enough?

Comment: It's a solution, I put two solutions that can solve your question.. the second one is better than first one

Comment: Does this work for you, @JonathanJohx? From JUnit 4 to JUnit 5, the annotation for "extending" the runner changed, from `@RunWith` to `@ExtendWith`. However, the latter doesn't work with the `SpringRunner`, which only works with JUnit 4. So how have you gotten Spring Boot to do its initialization with your solution?

Comment: @TedM.Young that works for migration, now it has to change his code what you does a mention obviously  :P

Comment: @JonathanJohx Sorry, I don't understand what you mean -- I tried what you proposed and it doesn't work for me. Can you provide a full working example (with a test that uses `@SpringBootTest`)?

Comment: @TedM.Young Thank you for your reply...so there is no smoother way of migrating from spring-boot JUnit-4 to JUnit-5

Comment: @JonathanJohx In my test, I can't use `@RunWith` because that's a JUnit 4 annotation. JUnit 5 requires `@ExtendWith`, but Spring Boot 1.5.x doesn't have anything that can be passed in. I'm unsure how Spring Boot can be initialized in the test. Can you post a working test that's annotated with `@SpringBootTest`?

Comment: I might explain you with details and many things. I suggest you take a look this link that I took as reference https://www.baeldung.com/junit-5-migration if you have some questions, let me know. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you have a project with the `Spring Framework` older than 5.0 or a project with the `SpringBoot` older than 2.0 version then you cannot find `SpringExtension` class in the sources of spring libs. This extension provide ability to run JUnit5 integration tests with Spring.

To fix this problem you need to add a Sam Brannen’s dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.sbrannen</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-test-junit5</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Also you need to add the jitpack in repositories block of your pom file:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>jitpack.io</id>
        <url>https://jitpack.io</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```